# Nmap only detect virtual hosts and not physical hosts (maybe segmented network)

Tags: network, nmap, nat, vmware

When my network settings is set to NAT and interface is eth0, this is the output of a simple nmap scan

```
root@pc:~# nmap 192.168.0.0/24

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-03-04 18:47 EST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.1
Host is up (0.00033s latency).
Not shown: 995 filtered ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
135/tcp  open  msrpc
139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds
1688/tcp open  nsjtp-data
2869/tcp open  icslap
MAC Address: 00:50:56:C0:00:08 (VMware)

Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.2
Host is up (0.000058s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
53/tcp open  domain
MAC Address: 00:50:56:FD:A1:12 (VMware)

Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.254
Host is up (0.000040s latency).
All 1000 scanned ports on 192.168.0.254 are filtered
MAC Address: 00:50:56:F9:42:C8 (VMware)

Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.3
Host is up (0.0000020s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http

Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (4 hosts up) scanned in 8.39 seconds
```

Only vmware machines are detected and the router in this scan, 192.168.0.1 is actually my windows pc running kali, acting as a router. This is also the case for bridged, host-only, whichever mode that shares adapter with vm host.

When I switched to a dedicated wifi adapter, wlan0 and connect to the network by wifi instead of wired, nmap scan output is:

```
root@Batman:~# nmap 192.168.0.0/24

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-03-04 18:52 EST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.1
Host is up (0.0065s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
80/tcp    open  http
52869/tcp open  unknown
MAC Address: 54:B8:0A:12:65:E4 (D-Link International)

Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.3
Host is up (0.011s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
62078/tcp open  iphone-sync
MAC Address: 00:26:BB:BC:A4:D3 (Apple)

Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.5
Host is up (0.0068s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
5060/tcp filtered sip
MAC Address: F8:23:B2:65:7A:01 (Huawei Technologies)

Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.6
Host is up (0.0040s latency).
Not shown: 995 filtered ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
135/tcp  open  msrpc
139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds
1688/tcp open  nsjtp-data
2869/tcp open  icslap
MAC Address: C0:18:85:0D:BE:93 (Hon Hai Precision Ind.)

Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.8
Host is up (0.0058s latency).
Not shown: 994 filtered ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
135/tcp   open  msrpc
139/tcp   open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp   open  microsoft-ds
554/tcp   open  rtsp
2869/tcp  open  icslap
10243/tcp open  unknown
MAC Address: 00:26:C6:BF:01:34 (Intel Corporate)

Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.9
Host is up (0.0000020s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http

Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (6 hosts up) scanned in 60.02 seconds
```

With wifi, nmap can detect all the actual physical hosts (smartphones, tablets, other pcs...) in my network and the router is D-Link.

How could I configure the settings in order to make nmap able scan physical hosts in NAT?

Comment: I would be surprised if this was an issue with nmap or use of it, instead I would suspect that the wired and wireless networks were segmented or firewalled somehow. Try connecting your host to the wireless network and use NAT and see if you see a difference.

Comment: Are you using the same subnet (192.168.0.0/24) for your actual network and your virtual VMWare network?

Comment: @David yes but I just changed it. Even when it was 192.168.129.0/24 (default), the output is the same, only virtual hosts.

Comment: Were you running the nmap of the external segment?

Comment: It would be useful to see the output of `ip addr` for this VM.

Comment: Because the connected device to the Access Point will use a separate Subnet , to make sure , check the IP address of the connected device.

Comment: Localhost ip is 192.168.0.3 in the first output